# Message collection data return no message

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Can someone help why this code returns no message while there are messages in my message collection on Firestore when I try to get the last message to display in the widget below?

[image]

```dart
class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {
  final ChatMethods chatMethods = ChatMethods();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          widthFactor: 5,
          child: Text(
            'Message',
            style: mystyle(
              20.0,
              Style.Colors.titleColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: chatMethods.fetchLastMessageBetween(
            senderId: firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid, receiverId: widget.uid),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            
            var docList = snapshot.data.docs;

            if (docList.isNotEmpty) {
              Message message = Message.fromMap(docList.last.data());
              return SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                child: Text(
                  message.message,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return Text(
              "No Message",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            );
          }
          return Text(
            "..",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {
  final ChatMethods chatMethods = ChatMethods();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          widthFactor: 5,
          child: Text(
            'Message',
            style: mystyle(
              20.0,
              Style.Colors.titleColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: chatMethods.fetchLastMessageBetween(
            senderId: firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid, receiverId: widget.uid),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            
            var docList = snapshot.data.docs;

            if (docList.isNotEmpty) {
              Message message = Message.fromMap(docList.last.data());
              return SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                child: Text(
                  message.message,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return Text(
              "No Message",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            );
          }
          return Text(
            "..",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

    class ChatMethods {
      Stream<QuerySnapshot> fetchLastMessageBetween({
        @required String senderId,
        @required String receiverId,
      }) =>
          messageCollection
              .doc(senderId)
              .collection(receiverId)
              .orderBy("timestamp")
              .snapshots();
    }
```

Comment: can you provide `fetchLastMessageBetween` from `ChatMethods`?

Comment: `class ChatMethods {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> fetchLastMessageBetween({
    @required String senderId,
    @required String receiverId,
  }) =>
      messageCollection
          .doc(senderId)
          .collection(receiverId)
          .orderBy("timestamp")
          .snapshots();
}`  @SimonSot

Comment: Seems like no mistakes here,  debug console gives no mistakes? For example PERMISSION DENIED or smth like that?

Comment: No, debug console gives no mistake. the outcome only display no message.

Comment: This is what i normally see in the debug console. Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)

Comment: anyone should please help me